# Ruby rails How to search/find a specific time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi i am working on a advance search and i want to compare requested_time to searchtime using to_i.. 
is there any way for me to convert requested_time: to requested_time.to_i? how?

search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

def search_reservations
    reservations = Reservation.all

    reservations = reservations.where(reservation_time: searchtime) if searchtime.present?
    reservations
end
end
```

Comment: what is `requested_time` here ?

Comment: the date of reservation

Comment: i just want to compare two attributes...so they become equal..sorry im bad in english hope you get my point.

Comment: Searching a specific time does not really make that much sense - it would only match a reservation that matches down to the second. Instead what you usually want is a range `where(requested_time: [time..time + 30.minutes])`

Comment: i want to get of rid of that "second" for me to compare a existing time to new one..

Comment: is there any way for me to convert requested_time:     to    requested_time.to_i?

Comment: Do you want to convert it then save it in that format?  Is requested_time saved as a string or a date object in your database?

Comment: requested_time is saved as a time object in my database

Comment: because requested_time = '2000-01-01 08:00:00' and searchtime = '2000-01-01 08:00:00' 
is not equal according to the system. why? any solution?

Comment: Remember that Time objects have fractional values that aren't visible using the .to_s method. you can use .change(usec: 0) to remove the fractional components for both dates.

Comment: @hypern how will i code that?